A foreword, but in the middle of the story
I'm writing a story that is a fiction within a fiction, presented as a written story compiled from oral sources by a fictional character who was a main character in a previous book.
Within this story, I have a foreword that is attributed to this MC, in which he explains the origin of the story he has compiled for the benefit of his child.  Within this story, I wanted to have further explanations from this MC in which he explains the different origins of each section, and an afterword in which the fictional writer wraps up the story.
However, while I'm calling the foreword a foreword, in that it comes before the main body of the story, and the afterword an afterword in that it comes after the story, I don't know what to call the MC author's interjections within the story.
So my question is: the story has a 'Foreword' and an 'Afterword'... but what do I call the 'words' in the middle of the story?

So it's an introduction or foreword for each story/section?

Answer after explanations in comments below this answer
If I understand you correctly, what you write is a fictional scholarly work. It is a collection of tales, collected and edited by a fictional scholar, who will write an introduction to those tales and provide scholarly commenatry to the tales.
I recommend that you pick up some scholarly collections of folk tales in a library and see how these books are structured and what each of their parts is called.
Having had quite a few of such books in my hands, my impression is that in these books the commentary is set off from the tales it collects typographically, that if it is named it is called something like "Introduction (to Ballad No. 3)" or "Commentary (on Snow White and the Seven Dwarves)", but that more often it has no label and is recognizable to the reader by its content (not a tale but commentary on a tale) and typography (different font or different indentation etc.).

Original answer
That's called commentary. Commentary is when the narrator comments on the story they narrate.
Example

I went to work, as I do every morning.

In this example, the first clause is narration (what the character experiences) and the second clause is commentary (in this case an explanation). In the example, the viewpoint character and the narrator are the same.
When the comment is about the narration itself, it is called metanarration.
Example

You may not believe me, but I saw the dragon just as you can see me now, and he spoke to me just as I speak to you.

In this example, "I saw the dragon and he spoke to me" is the story, the rest is metanarrative commentary, refering to the act of narrating itself.
Usually commentary is interwoven in the narration as side remarks, as in the two examples above, but if it is a longer section you may as well set it off in its own chapter. The commentary in your example is actually a part of the frame story, that is, a character in the frame story makes those comments. The frame story itself has its own narrator, who may be that character if the frame story is told in the first person or different if it is not, and which may have its own commentary (on the frame story).
I wouldn't label the foreword and afterword of the story within the frame story as "foreword" and "afterword", though, because we expect a foreword and afterword to come at the beginning and end of a book. Those aren't terms for parts of a (potentially oral) narrative, but for parts of the front and back matter of a printed book. Stories have a prologue and epilogue (which may be explicatory instead of eventful).
But whether you want to lable those parts "foreword/afterword" or "prologue/epilogue", I wouldn't do that. Readers expect these to sit at the beginning and end of a book. Oral narratives don't have labelled sections. When you tell your friends about your last holidays, you don't start by saying "Foreword" before you make your introductory remarks:

"Foreword. You probably know that I went to Spain last summer, right? Chapter one. So when we arrived in Alicante..."

What you could do is label those parts something like "Cato's introductory remarks about his tale", that is, name the narrator of the story within the frame story and describe the function that section has in the narrative. The parts of the story and the commentary sections would then be labelled "The first part of Cato's story" and "Cato makes some comments about his story", respectively. This, or something like it, is often done in older fiction like that from the 18th and 19th centuries.
Another option, and that's what I would do, is give these chapters the same titles of numbers that you give the frame narrative. If the frame narrative is chapters 1 to 5, then the story within the story, including its prologue etc., is chapters 6, 7, and so on. If the frame narrative has titles like "On the road" and "It is getting dark", then the story within the story has titles like that, too, e.g. "A tale" for the first of its chapters and "The king and the maiden" for the second.

The book is not an oral narrative.  It is an in-story written story based on in-story oral narratives, and commented upon by the transcriber, who is a story character.  So, he would be justified in adding comments to his transcription of the oral stories... wouldn't he?

@MontyWild You have a frame story in which there is someone who writes something and then you present that which he writes? I still wouldn't label those chapters "Foreword" etc. That will be confusing ("Why is there a foreword in the middle of the book?"). I would explain in the frame narrative that what now follows is the foreword (either at the end of the preceding chapter or at the beginning of the foreword chapter) and then present the text of the foreword. You could give a title like "Cato's foreword to his collection of folk tales", but I would advise against calling it just "Foreword".

This 'book within the story' is an entire book.  The MC's foreword will actually be the book's foreword, etcetera.

@MontyWild See the edit to the top of my answer.


I have a foreword that is attributed to this MC, in which he explains
the origin of the story he has compiled for the benefit of his child.
Within this story, I wanted to have further explanations from this MC
in which he explains the different origins of each section, and an
afterword in which the fictional writer wraps up the story.

Epistolary Novel
A couple centuries ago this kind of framing device for fiction was normal. Nearly every genre novel was presented diegetically within the story as a collection of private letters, or a found manuscript, or the new translation of a forgotten medieval text.
Now epistolary novel is a catch-all term for any story that's told through collected documents.
Generally the framing device involves an introduction and conclusion from a fictional editor or translator. The core of the novel is a 'direct copy' of an earlier story told by someone else. The 'Editor' might provide a mid-novel explanation for a gap in time, or comment about a missing reply that remains ambiguous, or when switching the source material.
There are parodies from the 1700s making fun of clunky contrivances to make this work. Readers weren't fooled, it was just how popular novels were written. It's believed this structure evolved to mimic how real events would be retold 'virally' through letters, copied word-for-word from another letter.
(Mary Shelley's Frankenstein uses an epistolary frame story of a sea captain trapped in ice at the North Pole, who writes Viktor's testimony in a letter to the captain's sister.)
Diegetic Narrator
At the other end of the spectrum you might have a diegetic narrator who is actually a character who is retelling a story. They attempt to be neutral, but can't help commenting and correcting the source material.
The result is a dual narrative or a dual perspective where the events told by the 'core' narrator are being undermined by commentary and criticism from the frame device. This outside 'Editor' loses some of their authority by raising doubts in the reader's mind about the validity of both narrators – where there are 2 versions, there is some doubt what is true.
The more this narrator interjects themselves onto the reader, the more secure you will need to be with this character's narrative voice. The author will need to transmit this person's biases and fallibilities through subtext and their own words. The things they chose to comment on are just as telling as their commentary. As a main character disconnected from the events of the core story, the narrator may need a clever arc of their own that works as a counterpoint or a foil to the main story.
